# Not getting the correct totals using Cognos Report Studio. Need to get totals that show up in column

Tags: oracle, cognos

[image]

newparts_calc

```
if (([MonthToDateQuery].[G/L Account] = 4200 and [Query1].[G_L_Group] = 'NEW')) THEN ([Credit Amount]-[Debit Amount]) ELSE (0)
```

Data Item1
total([newparts_calc])

I need Data Item1 to return newparts_calc values only.

So for example in  1st row Data Item1 should be 8,540.8, but is 34,163.2

Whats wrong? how do i fix?

***REVISED QUESTION***

I apologize for not making sense on the original question.

I have many of the calc's that im trying to gather and put on a crosstab. I want to see sales by month (row) and part category (column)

[Query2] is the one shown in picture above.
It joins [MonthToDateQuery] AND [Query1]
The join is on 'Invoice' and carnality is `1..1 = 1..1`

[MonthToDateQuery] is based on the package im working in. General ledger. It supplies the g/l entries for each sales g/l account
[Query1] is a SQL query i brought in to be able to break out categories even further from g/l group. 
For example g/l account 4300 is rebuilt. However i needed to break out even further to see Rebuilt-Production and Rebuilt-New. I can do that with the g/l group.

I saw in my g/l account ledger entries that it referenced the invoice number. So thats how i tied in my SQL.

So as you can see from the table below (which is the view tabular data from query) i need a total. I have tried plugging newparts_calc into my crosstab and setting aggregation to total but the numbers still dont seem right. I dont think i have something set as it should be.

All the calc's im doing are based on single or multiple G/L Accounts and single or multiple G/L Groups.

Any Advice?

As you can see the problem seems to be duplicate invoice numbers.
How can i fix?
[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do with your data item 1. But it looks like you've got some sort of cross product going on (notice newparts_calc always divides into [data item one] evenly.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things come to mind:

-Set the processing order to 2

-Since your calc is always a multiple and you are joining two queries, you may need to check your cardinality. Sometimes it helps to add derived queries to ensure you are working with the correct grain.

Comment: Processing order is something I'm not familiar. Will check that out. I did check cardinality and it is set to one and only one which is right I'm pretty sure. Will look at that too. Thanks for the response

Comment: I cannot figure out how to adjust the processing order. any help on that?

Comment: I figured out distinct works! but if i have a day where 2 of the newparts_calc's were the same it will only count one. any way around that?

Comment: I have revised my original question. please help if you can

Answer (score 0):

I'm obviously missing something, but if you want

> I need Data Item1 to return newparts_calc values only.

just use newparts_calc, without total? That would give you proper value for row 1 -)

If you need a running-total for days (sum of values for previous days) — you should use a running_total function.

Comment: I have revised my original question. please help if you can

Comment: You have fact tables at different levels of granularity and instead of trying to solve at report level you should do adjust you framework manager model to allow for proper stitch queries. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/cognos/reporting/advanced_report_design/page605.html

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, one of your two queries is returning multiple rows for each invoice, which will cause this double counting.  Look at the output of the two queries and see if that's happening.  If so, then you just need to work out how to collapse that down to one row per invoice.

Answer (score 0):

Per your new question - The underlying data has got to be causing the issue. Its clearly not 1:1 (note that even though this is what your stated cardinality is, Cognos does not enforce 1:1). Invoice number is not unique, GL Group is at a lower level.

Comment: Yes, i understand that. What can i do? is there anyway to get the data i need?